# Is Fourier transform defined on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ only for $p \in [1, 2]$?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Is  Fourier transform defined on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ only for $p \in [1, 2]$?

From Lieb and Loss's Analysis, they extend the definition of Fourier transform from $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ to $L^p(\mathbb{R}), p \in (1, \infty)$, using 
$$
\| FT(f) \|_q \leq C_{p,q} \|f\|_p
$$
which they said only holds when $p \in (1,2]$. Does that mean that FT cannot be defined on $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ with $p \in (2, \infty)$, possibly via other means?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I recall having heard that the Fourier transform cannot be defined in $L^p$ space with $p>2$ if we want to confine ourselves to function spaces. That is, for any $p>2$ there exists a function $f\in L^p$ such that the distributional Fourier transform (the same Pavel mentions below) $\hat{f}$ *is not a function*, meaning that it does not belong to $L^1_{\text{loc}}$. But I cannot prove this and I cannot point you to any reference, so please don't take me too seriously.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fourier transform is a linear operator. When defining an operator, we should think not only of the domain space, but also of the target. It is true that Fourier transform is not a bounded operator from $L^p(\mathbb R)$ to $L^q(\mathbb R)$ ($1/p+1/q=1$) when $p>2$. The issue is that large $p$ allows the function to have a pretty heavy "tail", which on the Fourier side results in bad local behavior.

But it is possible to define the Fourier transform of any function in $L^p(\mathbb R)$, by considering $f$ as a tempered distribution. Then the transform becomes an automorphism of the topological vector space of tempered distributions. In fact, the Wikipedia article on [Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions) covers this, and links to an article on distributions.

Related MSE question: [Fourier transform in $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146067/fourier-transform-in-lp)

Comment: The key fact is that $L^p \subset L^1_\mathrm{loc}$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, but $L^1_{\rm loc}$ by itself would not be enough to get a *tempered* distribution.

Comment: Thanks! +1. I need to spend some time to understand distributions and FT on them. But let me ask this question. Is Fourier series also defined firstly as $L^1([a,b]) \to l^{\infty}$, and then extended to $L^p([a,b]) \to l^q, p \in (1, 2], 1/p + 1/q =1$? I didn't find the answer in the Wikipedia article for FS, and some books I have. So references are also appreciated.

Comment: The comparison with Fourier series in an imperfect one and here is why : $\mathcal{L}_p\big([a,b]\big) \subseteq \mathcal{L}_1\big([a,b]\big)$ for all $1 < p \leq \infty$ so it suffices to define the Fourier series for $\mathcal{L}_1\big([a,b]\big)$ and the extension to $\mathcal{L}_p\big([a,b]\big)$ is immediate. However $\mathcal{L}_p(\mathbb{R}) \not\subseteq \mathcal{L}_1(\mathbb{R})$.