# When $\|\mathcal{F}^{-1} (\phi \hat{f})\|_{L^{p}} \leq C \|\hat{f}\|_{L^{p}}$?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^d)$ and let $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb C$ be function.
 Let $1\leq p \leq \infty.$
Question:

> Can we say $\|\mathcal{F}^{-1} (\phi \hat{f})\|_{L^{p}} \leq C \|\hat{f}\|_{L^{p}}$?
>   Can we say $\|\mathcal{F}^{-1} (\phi \hat{f})\|_{L^{p}} \leq C \|f\|_{L^{p}}$? $C$ is some constant.

(where $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$is inverse Fourier transform, and $\hat{.}$ is Fourier transform)

**Motivation:** What is a Bernstein's multiplier estimate? Is this applicable in this kind of situation?

Comment: Your second estimate is true by Young's convolution inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As Jose27 said, the second estimate is true by [Young's convolution inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young's_inequality#Young.27s_inequality_for_convolutions) because $\mathcal F^{-1}(\phi \hat f)$ is the convolution of $f$ with $\mathcal F^{-1}(\phi)$, and the latter is integrable.

The first inequality is true only for $p=2$. The Fourier transform is only bounded from $L^p$ to $L^q$ when $1\le p\le 2$ and $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$. Since you want $q=p$ here, $p=2$ is the only option. See [Fourier transform in $L^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146067).