# Boundness of Fourier thansform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Given $1\leq p\leq\infty$, prove that if it exists a constant C s.t. $$\|\hat{f}\|_{p'}\leq C \|f\|_p$$here $1/p+1/p'=1;$
then $1\leq p\leq 2$

I know that if $1\leq p\leq 2$, then it exists a constant C s.t. $$\|\hat{f}\|_{p'}\leq C \|f\|_p$$ and I have no idea how to prove this result.

Any idea will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146067/fourier-transform-in-lp

Comment: If not than the Fourier transform is a linear homeomorphism between $L^p $and $L^p'$ which is a contradiction，